# how to wrap an external library in a conan package, adding support for building as a shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I am attempting to wrap Google's Gumbo parser as a Conan package.
I have mostly succeed supporting Linux Mac and Windows, but I am having some issues creating (and consuming) it as a shared library in Windows (.dll + .lib).

My current progress is [here](https://github.com/ruipires/conan-gumbo).
I have decided to bypass Gumbo's autoconf build system a provide a CMakeLists.txt that I copy when fetching the sources. This way I hoped to be able to also fully support Windows.

I am not very familiar with Visual C++, but from what I understand Visual C++ is different from other compilers in that it does not export symbols by default, where Gcc and Clang export everything.

This is causing my Conan package to fail its build in some scenarios, because in shared mode it is just generating a .dll (and no corresponding .lib).

Tried using CMake's GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER module, but it did little to help, since then I'd have to actually use the macros it generated in the methods that should be exported. But I'm just trying to wrap the library without having to fork and adapt it.

Another option would be to use a [.def file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b9xe492.aspx). This might work in this case (not that many symbols to export), but it would not be very helpful to me (harder to test if I actually exported everything I should have, harder to maintain, not very helpful for solving the same issue in other situations with far more symbols to export).

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Seems a bit complex, I will be able to clone your project tonight and have a look, but unfortunately, it will be some hours.

Comment: I think the def file can be the best option for you. As @drodi said it's a complex problem and doesn't have a unique solution. The truly problem is the lack of DLL support for Google's Gumbo's parser. The better way should be fork que repository, add CMake and DLL support with symbols or a def file and then make a pull request (you can always package your fork if it's not merged). I think there are isolated problems, first the DLL support and then the conan package. Maybe we can help you with the DLL support with little time! ;)

Comment: I know its a bit complex, it has made for excellent learning material so far. I am also considering just dropping support for shared builds on visual studio, but that feels like giving up.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you, having a whole package with all settings combinations gives you a lot of satisfaction :) But no one can use this library as a DLL with or without conan, and just the static packages in conan makes a GREAT improvement! Moreover, in my experience often developers prefers to embed the static library in his shared library or just link against that. By the way, the "fPIC" option can allow embeding the static library in a shared library, you can see an example here: https://github.com/lasote/conan-jansson with autotools, you can also use it with CMake setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS